# SQLite Database in Android not returning anything

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to read data from SQLite database that exists and has the required values. For some reason, the cursor doesn't return anything or the execution halts - I don't know what the reason is as there is no error of any sort.
Nothing seems to happen after printing(in logcat) :

> TableAllSyncInboxHandlerThread: handleMessage(): reading values from
> TABLE_ALL

Code:

```
db = db_helper.getReadableDatabase();
                    String[] projection_id = {
                            BaseColumns._ID,
                            SpamBusterContract.TABLE_ALL.COLUMN_CORRES_INBOX_ID
                    };
                    String selection_id = null;
                    String[] selection_args = null;
                    String sort_order = SpamBusterContract.TABLE_ALL.COLUMN_SMS_EPOCH_DATE + " DESC";
                    Log.d(TAG, "TableAllSyncInboxHandlerThread: handleMessage(): reading values from TABLE_ALL");
 ------>            Cursor cursor_read_id = db.query(SpamBusterContract.TABLE_ALL.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                            projection_id,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
                            selection_id,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
                            selection_args,          // The values for the WHERE clause
                            null,                   // don't group the rows
                            null,                   // don't filter by row groups
                            sort_order               // The sort order
                    );
                    if (!cursor_read_id.moveToFirst()) {
                        tableall_is_empty = true;
                        Log.d(TAG, "TableAllSyncInboxHandlerThread: handleMessage(): TABLE_ALL is empty");
                    } else {
                        tableall_is_empty = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "TableAllSyncInboxHandlerThread: handleMessage(): TABLE_ALL not empty");
                    }
                    cursor_read_id.close();
```

What might be the reason?

EDIT : got the answer. Stupid me! I started a transaction on that table in some other part of my code. I wrote `db.beginTransaction()` and forgot to end it.

Comment: What do you mean by *execution halts*? Does the app crash?

Comment: no app does not crash. The above code is getting executed on background thread. so no app crash. Just, nothing, no error, no app crash, no database retrieved, no printing of log statements after printing "reading values from TABLE_ALL"

Comment: If you don't see the log statements then the code is not executed, so the problem is not with this code.